# Solve an equation for $a$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I've got this equation:

$$\sqrt{s^2 - v^2} = 2a\sinh\frac{h}{2a}$$

and I need to get $a$.

Now I've been trying to solve this equation for $2$ days now, and I just can't do it. Just to be clear, this is not something I got for homework, this is a step in the making of an function that represents a catenary. I know a catenary is just $$f(x)=\cosh\left(\frac{x+a}{b}\right)+c$$ but I want to make it 'hang' between two points, whereas the base function uses the bottom point of the line. If anyone can help me with this, I would be extremely happy!

Thanks in advance,

Lenard

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form solution for $a$ in this case.

Comment: ok, thanks for the mathjax, didn't know how to do it. So if there isn't a solution to this equation, I'd have to: iterate through a values and test them and see which one comes closest to solving the problem (I'm using java) or using a graphic device to intersect the lines. Is that right?

Comment: What I have tried is: some online equation solvers, to no result. I've tried writing it in different forms, but that didn't work either. I've asked some friends, but they couldn't do it either. I've tried to find other ways to solve this too (such as making the function in a totally other way), but i couldn't find any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{s^2 - v^2} = 2a\sinh\left(\frac{h}{2a}\right)\implies \frac{\sqrt{s^2 - v^2} }h=\left(\frac{2a}h\right) \sinh\left(\frac{h}{2a}\right)$$
Let $x=\frac{h}{2a}$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{s^2 - v^2} }h$; so, you need to solve the equation
$$b=\frac{\sinh(x)} x$$ or, say better, to find the zero of the function $$f(x)=\sinh(x)-b\, x$$ where $b > 1$.

Excluding the trivial root $x=0$, $f'(x)$ cancels at $x_1=\cosh ^{-1}(b)$ and
$$f(x_1)=\sqrt{b^2-1}-b \cosh ^{-1}(b)$$ which always negative while $f''(x_1)>0$. Using Taylor series at $x=x_1$
$$f(x)=\left(\sqrt{b^2-1}-b \cosh ^{-1}(b)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{b^2-1} \left(x-\cosh
   ^{-1}(b)\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\cosh ^{-1}(b)\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the high order terms, the solution of $f(x)=0$ can then be approximated as 
$$x_2=\cosh ^{-1}(b)+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{b-1}{b+1}} b \cosh
   ^{-1}(b)+1-b}{b-1}}$$ Further analysis shows that $f(x_2)>0$ making $x_2$ to be an overestimate of the solution.

Newton method solves the problem easily using $x_2$ as a guess. Since $f(x_2) \times f''(x_2) >0$, by Darboux-Fourier theorem, the process would converge without any overshoot of the solution.

For illustration purposes, let us try for $b=12.34$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 5.3090664 \\
 1 & 4.9083105 \\
 2 & 4.7794841 \\
 3 & 4.7680733 \\
 4 & 4.7679903
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for eight significant figures.

Let use do the same using $b=123.45$ and get as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 8.5120147 \\
 1 & 7.9043585 \\
 2 & 7.5967115 \\
 3 & 7.5302218 \\
 4 & 7.5275579 \\
 5 & 7.5275538
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Using numerical analysis, we can show that, for $1 < b \leq 200$, the solution of the equation is "almost" given by 
$$x \approx 0.863698\, x_2+0.176469$$ where the parameters are highly significant
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.863698 & 0.000077 & \{0.863546,0.863849\} \\
 b & 0.176469 & 0.000612 & \{0.175269,0.177669\} 
\end{array}$$ For the two worked examples, this would give $4.76190$ and $7.52827$ which seems to be quite good. More than likely, one iteration of Newton method will be sufficient.

Around $x=0$, we have by Taylor
$$\frac{\sinh(x)} x=1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}+\frac{x^6}{5040}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ and series reversion would give for "small" values of $b$
$$x=\sqrt{6} \sqrt{b-1}-\frac{3}{10} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} (b-1)^{3/2}+\frac{321
    }{2800}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(b-1)^{5/2}+O\left((b-1)^{7/2}\right)$$ showing the key role of $\sqrt{b-1}$.

Looking at numerical results, this gave the idea of a very simplistic and totally empirical model
$$x= \alpha\,\sqrt{b-1}\,\,\frac{ 1+\beta\, \sqrt{b-1}}{1+\gamma \,\sqrt{b-1}}$$
which, for the same range $1 < b \leq 200$, leads to a quite good fit $(R^2=0.99996)$ and highly significant parameters
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 \alpha  & 2.86091 & 0.00434 & \{2.85240,2.86943\} \\
 \beta   & 0.00667 & 0.00019 & \{0.00629,0.00704\} \\
 \gamma  & 0.31814 & 0.00130 & \{0.31559,0.32068\} \\
\end{array}$$
For the two worked examples, this would give as estimates $4.75558$ and $7.51990$. Making one single iteration of Newton would give $4.76809$ and 
$7.52759$ which are almost the solutions.

Comment: Hey, firstly, thank you very much for your answer. I wonder how you made $2h/a$ from $2a$ only by dividing by $h$. Maybe this is just my stupid head again (wouldn't be the first time :P)

Comment: @LenardvanderMaas. Easy : **typo**. I shall improve my solution.

Comment: @LenardvanderMaas. Notice that, when $b$ is large, a good approximation is $x=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 b}\right)$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. For the worked examples, this would give $4.76790$ and $7.52755$.

Comment: Wow! you're really good at math!! I'm going to see how I can use this, thank you so much!

Comment: @LenardvanderMaas. I enjoy math and almost applied math ! When I see an equation, I cannot resist ! By the way, if you think that this is an answer, may be, you could accept it in order other people know that this is a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to add another answer.*

As said, needing to find the zero of
$$f(x)=\sinh(x)-b x$$ will require an interative method. Newton iterates will be given by
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{\sinh (x_n)-x_n \cosh (x_n)}{b-\cosh (x_n)}$$ As usual, the problem is to define a "good" value for the starting point $x_0$.

For $\color{red}{b \leq 3}$, using Padé approximants built at $x=0$, we have
$$\frac{\sinh(x)} x=\frac{551 x^4+22260 x^2+166320}{75 x^4-5460 x^2+166320}$$ giving as approximation 
$$x=\sqrt{6} \sqrt{\frac{455 b+1855-\sqrt{35} \sqrt{-3985 b^2+130862 b+25583}}{75
   b-551}}$$ The table below shows some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1.00 & 0.00000 &  0.00000 \\
 1.25 & 1.18273 &  1.18273 \\
 1.50 & 1.62214 &  1.62213 \\
 1.75 & 1.93302 &  1.93300 \\
 2.00 & 2.17739 &  2.17732 \\
 2.25 & 2.37978 &  2.37963 \\
 2.50 & 2.55292 &  2.55265 \\
 2.75 & 2.70439 &  2.70395 \\
 3.00 & 2.83911 &  2.83845
\end{array}
\right)$$
For $\color{red}{b \geq 3}$,we have 
$$\frac{\sinh(x)} x\approx \frac{e^x} {2x}\implies x=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 b}\right)$$ where appears Lambert function. The table below shows some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 3.00 & 2.83315 &  2.83845 \\
 3.25 & 2.95545 &  2.95952 \\
 3.50 & 3.06642 &  3.06962 \\
 3.75 & 3.16801 &  3.17058 \\
 4.00 & 3.26169 &  3.26380 \\
 4.25 & 3.34861 &  3.35037 \\
 4.50 & 3.42970 &  3.43117 \\
 4.75 & 3.50567 &  3.50693 \\
 5.00 & 3.57715 &  3.57823 \\
 5.25 & 3.64463 &  3.64557 \\
 5.50 & 3.70853 &  3.70935 \\
 5.75 & 3.76921 &  3.76994 \\
 6.00 & 3.82698 &  3.82762
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Ok, I think this is incredibly impressive. Question: the last functio results in $sinh(x)/x$. Is there a way to get x from that? I'm positive that there is but my mind is not working in this boiling hot room...